# How to cast/convert a Stack of Integers to an Array of doubles?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, stack

I have a `Stack` of `Integer`s. I need an `array` of `double`s.

I know stack has `Stack#toArray`, but this returns an `Object` array.

How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, arrays of a concrete types are obtained like that:

```
Integer[] array = stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
```

But since you need to change the type of the array, you'd better iterate:

```
int i = 0;
double[] doubles = new double[stack.size()];
for (Integer value : stack) {
    doubles[i++] = value.doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unless you do it iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can cast the Object array returned by the Stack#toArray iteratively to integer...

Comment: It is not possible to downcast arrays, but luckily there is an other signature of toArray() which allows you to provide an array of the correct type. But it will not help in this case because it was asked for a conversion from Integer to double.